# Is there a difference between TParallel.&For and TParallel.For?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Is there a difference between `TParallel.&For` and `TParallel.For` ?

Both can be compiled in Delphi 10 Seattle. so which one should I stick to?

Comment: There is no difference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The method definition for `TParallel.&For` requires the ampersand to escape a *reserved* word (`for`).  You don't need to use it when calling the method except in cases where there would be ambiguity.

For example :

```
 with TParallel do begin
    &For(...)  // etc 
 end;
```

I can't imagine why you would ever want to do that, however.

If it were in one of your own classes, mind you, any internal calls to an escaped method would require either the ampersand or an explicit class or instance (`self`) identifier.

`TParallel` is a sealed class, so the point is moot in this case.  You will never be working within it or within a descendent class.

Comment: Presumably it's only needed in the declaration of the type and not the implementation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's also necessary in the implementation.  You would think the scope could be resolved at that point, but omitting it in the implementation produces a compiler error (`Expected IN but received FOR`).

Comment: Thank you for that, interesting